# Magento 2 - Check if customer and customer addres created from admin backend

Tags: event-observer, magento2.4, customer-address

Is there a way in Magento 2 to check/know if a customer and a customer addres is created/edited from admin panel ?

I was thinking using a oberver on `customer_address_save_before` and `adminhtml_customer_save_before` but I'm not sure it concern only creation/edition made in admin panel

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this observer you can use "adminhtml_customer_save_before"

I think you can use "adminhtml_customer_save_after" or "adminhtml_customer_prepare_save"

Please use this if you want to set a flag for add only "adminhtml_customer_prepare_save"

This will work for both add and edit but if you don't want to flag for edit just use customer factory load with email and check for customer id if it is null set the flag for admin created

Note: You have to create a flag column too for the same

Happy Coding

Comment: After some tries, adminhtml_customer_save_after seems do the job for the customer.
I'm still need an observer for address but for what I want to do I think I whill have to use a preference of the controller